# On click event, Silverlight child window resize to show more options

Tags: c#, silverlight, animation, childwindow

I have a Silverlight child window in place,

however I want to hide certain options i.e. check boxes from the user until a specific item on the current form is clicked.

Once that item has been click I need the window to resize dynamically to show the checkboxes down the side of the window. I believe this would be using an animation to make the transition smooth however I have no idea if this is even possible?
Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read about animations? What have you tried in terms of making bare functionality?

Comment: Well i have added the checkboxes to the side of the existing form, I can make them visible or hide them on the click event, however I would prefer if the form resized smoothly through an animation to show or hide the options.

Comment: Right, so what have you read about animations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using an accordion or an expander control, they have the functionality to animate grow and shrink the specific content they contain! Hope that this solves your problem

Comment: Thanks I will have a look and mark your answer correct if appropriate.